# Eclipse Plugin: Palette Viewer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, html-editor

I am creating an eclipse plugin and added HTML editor in it. I want to create palette viewer which can contain the HTML tags in it. So that the developer can directly choose the tags from the palette viewer. I don't find much document of palette viewer tutorial or sample on net which guide me how to create this view programmatically. Can some one help me or give me some links?

Comment: What 'HTML editor"? Something you have written, or the Eclipse WST HTML editor, or something else? Is this Content Assist you are asking about or something else?

Comment: I have to create my own custom HTML editor, so that I can do changes in that. I am talking about palette viewer which can contain HTML tags and can be put directly to source code without writing the source code.